# How to create running group with range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has two columns
i.e.

- `CreatedOn: DateTime` when the record is created,
- `IsResponseExpected: (Yes/No)` indicates the expected result.

Sample data:

```
CreatedOn           IsResponseExpected
--------------------------------------
2021-11-29 11:03    Yes
2021-11-29 11:03    Yes
2021-11-29 10:58    Yes
2021-11-29 10:58    Yes
2021-11-29 10:53    Yes
2021-11-29 10:53    Yes
2021-11-29 10:48    Yes
2021-11-29 10:48    Yes
2021-11-29 10:43    Yes
2021-11-29 10:43    Yes
2021-11-29 10:38    Yes
2021-11-29 10:38    Yes
2021-11-29 10:33    Yes
2021-11-29 10:33    Yes
2021-11-29 10:28    No
2021-11-29 10:28    Yes
2021-11-29 10:23    Yes
2021-11-29 10:23    Yes
2021-11-29 10:18    Yes
```

The `IsResponseExpected` are not in any sequence over the minutes of days, sometimes it is Yes sometimes it is No.

I can query the table and see the data, but the result is huge and does need to be summarized for analytics.

I would like to do a running group on the table so that I can see three columns

i.e. From, To, and IsResponseExpected.

Something like below this:

```
From               To                  IsResponseExpected
---------------------------------------------------------
2021-11-29 11:03   2021-11-29 10:23       Yes
2021-11-29 10:28   2021-11-29 10:28       No
2021-11-29 10:28   2021-11-29 10:18       Yes
```

How should I achieve the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a `Gaps-and-Islands` problem

Here is one approach using the window function `row_number()` to create the `Grp`

```
with cte as ( 
Select * 
      ,Grp = row_number() over (order by [CreatedOn]) - row_number() over (partition by [IsResponseExpected] order by [CreatedOn])
from YourTable
)
Select [From] = min([CreatedOn])
      ,[to]   = max([CreatedOn])
      ,[IsResponseExpected]
 From  cte
 Group By Grp,[IsResponseExpected]
 Order by [From],[To]
```

**Results**

[image]